# How does SimpleCORSFilter work?

Tags: spring

How does `SimpleCORSFilter` work in this example?

[Enabling Cross Origin Requests for a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/).

I only see a declaration of `SimpleCORSFilter` class but no instance. I tried `ctrl+f` to search the example page but can't find anywhere this class be instantiated.
How does it work?

I am new to Spring and Java.

So more detail more helpful. Thx.

Comment: Could you provide more details, and show what you have tried so far?

Comment: In fact, you're asking what a servlet filter is, right? Read http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html

Comment: @Mikael Hellman I haven't try this example. I am confused when learning this example. Because I only see a declaration of `SimpleCORSFilter` class but no instance. I tried ctrl+f to  search the example, and can't find anywhere this class be instantiated.

Comment: @JB Nizet I read the doc you provided. Will this filter be searched and then called? In my opinions, once I defined a class named like filter. I will pass this class as a parameters to the main function to let main function know to  do this filter.

Comment: You also need to learn about spring and spring-boot. The filter is a spring bean, and spring will thus create it and invoke it when necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A main point of Spring is a mechanism called [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). Spring allows you to mark your classes, instance variables and so on with special annotations. Spring will look for those annotations and configure your application according to them.

In your example you annotate your filter with `@Component`:

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter
```

And you annotate your Application class with `@SpringBootApplication`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application
```

The second annotation (`@SpringBootApplication`) tells Spring to search through your project for `@Component` annotations. As you annotated your filter with this, Spring will find your filter and instantiate it automatically. That's how your filter will be created and put to the right place.

Comment: But if I put `SimpleCORSFilter` in different package, then it is not working.What could be the possible cause ??

Comment: A Spring Boot application will only scan the packages under the class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`. So if your `@SpringBootApplication` is under `my.super.package` all packages like `my.super.package.one` or `my.super.package.one.two` will be scanned. But not `my.other.package`.

Comment: thanks@Thomas Uhrig ! I used @ComponentScan("{..basepackagename..}") to make spring application to scan that package too.